# How can we send dot in smtp protocol

Tags: smtp

If we want when using the SMTP protocol, inside the text a

\n

.

\n

What should we do so that it is not confused with the endpoint of the email in the SMTP protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RFC has a separate section about the escape mechanism for sending a lone dot on a line; it's colloquially called "dot stuffing".

In brief, any leading dot on a line needs to be escaped with another dot. So, to send a line containing one literal dot, you'd send

```
..
```

and to send a line containing two literal dots, you'd send

```
...
```

etc, with the usual `<CRLF>` line terminators required by the protocol (your example seems to incorrectly assume just `<LF>` which is often tolerated in practice, but technically not correct). The receiving server correspondingly strips any initial dot from each line of the data.

The RFC refers to this mechanism as "transparency"; [RFC 5321 section 4.5.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [helpful link to the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#:%7E:text=The%20custom%20of,mail%20data%20indication.) (top of page 37 if the link isn't working). Here's the important takeaway:

```
The custom of accepting lines ending only in <LF>, as a concession to
non-conforming behavior on the part of some UNIX systems, has proven
to cause more interoperability problems than it solves, and SMTP
server systems MUST NOT do this, even in the name of improved
robustness.  In particular, the sequence "<LF>.<LF>" (bare line
feeds, without carriage returns) MUST NOT be treated as equivalent to
<CRLF>.<CRLF> as the end of mail data indication.
```

Basically SMTP servers are not actually listening for `\n.\n` as the terminator. Instead they're expecting `\r\n.\r\n`.

The `\n` character is a newline (in the RFC it's called `LF`) whereas the `\r\n` characters constitute a carriage return (in the RFC it's called `CRLF`).

So, it's an important distinction that SMTP servers actually terminate data with `<CRLF>.<CRLF>` not `<LF>.<LF>`, otherwise SMTP servers would run into exactly the issue you bring up here.

Answer (score 0):

NB: Depending on the SMTP servers involved, you may also need to check for .

(I've just discovered today that the reason why around 1% of my emails fail to completely send was because of this.)